# Slow down section of Google Earth studio program

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-studio

I have programmed a 90 second sequence in Google Earth Studio and I want to slow down the middle section only.

(I think there could be a long and dirty workaround by changing the overall time of the video in project settings and selecting scaling, then swaping in copies of the original start and finish, and link them all back together - but there must be an easier way to do this!?)

If there is a better forum for Google Earth Studio programming questions, please share in Comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way to slow down a section of Google Earth Studio but it's still a bit clunky.

1. Increase the overall length of the animation in project setting, see above.
2. Highlight all the keyframes AFTER and including the end of the section to stretch (the spots on the keyframe editor, bottom half of screen).
3. Drag the selected keyframes to the right. This increases the time to get between the 2 keyframes (section to be stretched) automatically slowing the section down.

Tip 1: Selecting multiple keyframes (spots) - click and drag mouse but remember to select all keyframes including those out of sight. Scroll down to lower attributes.

Tip 2: Roll up (shrink) attributes before selecting multiple keyframes. This usually means that you can see everything without needing to scroll down. Click the small arrow next to the attribute (far left of keyframe editor).

Tip 3: You can always select keyframes manually, just hold down shift when you click on them to add to original selection.

Add to the comments if you know an easier way slow down a section of Google Earth Studio.